# How to get the completed downloaded size when using .net WeClient DownloadFileAsync

Tags: .net, webclient

I use WebClient instance to download streaming data to a local file asynchronously. For WebClient there is an event DownloadFileCompleted which I can check for completed download. But AsyncCompletedEventArgs argument receive does not have any way to determine the completed file size.

Can you please suggest me a way to determine the downloaded size.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += webClient_DownloadFileCompleted;
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), localPath); 

    void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
// it seems 'e' arg does not have any useful information related to the download.
}
```

When I use DownloadProgressChanged event , it fires twice even for 100% percentage download. So I cannot accurately calculate the total downloaded sizes for different async webclient download threads.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use HttpClient and his async api instead. Than you can read response http headers for e.g. content-length. As an example, please see code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var uri = "http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.3.0/amd64/iso-cd/MD5SUMS";
        var path = "output.txt";
        DownloadFileAsync(uri, path);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void DownloadFileAsync(string uri, string path)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync(uri);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.Headers.ContentLength);
        using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var localStream = File.Create(path))
            responseStream.CopyTo(localStream);
    }
```